# No on-board sound on Dell Optiplex SX-280 post Linux Mint Petra Install

Tags: linux, linux-mint, audio

Not sure this fits in here..

We recently installed Linux Mint Petra on this small-form-factor dell desktop.

The weird thing is, the sound does not work on board, but works on a speaker connected to the audio out. I've checked all details I could about the alsa mixer, sound card mute check etc. All seems fine. Also looked to see if the box had any mute on/off button but there's none in sight.

Previously, when the box had Windows XP, there indeed was on-board sound, and thus there was no need to use external speakers for the audio.

Has anyone come across this issue, or is there anything else I could check. Any online search result only talks about general sound-card issues, but this is specifically a case of onboard sound not working.

Of course one could say why not just plug in speakers, but I would like to understand what the problem might be here and find a solution.

This question was seen as not relevant in the ubuntu forum when [originally posted there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414034/no-on-board-sound-on-dell-optiplex-sx-280-post-linux-mint-petra-install?noredirect=1#comment533591_414034).

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ICH6 ]: ICH4 - Intel ICH6
            Intel ICH6 with AD1981B at irq 23

$ sudo lshw
     *-multimedia
    description: Multimedia audio controller
    product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1e.2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.2
    version: 03
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=0
    resources: irq:23 ioport:ec00(size=256) ioport:e8c0(size=64) memory:dfebfe00-dfebffff memory
```

```
$ lsmod | grep pcspkr
pcspkr 12630 0

$ lsmod | grep snd  
snd_intel8x0 33069 3
snd_ac97_codec 105668 1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus 12642 1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm 89488 3 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0
snd_page_alloc 14230 2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi 13132 0
snd_seq_midi_event 14475 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi 25094 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq 55383 2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device 14137 3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer 24447 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd 60790 13   snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore 12600 1 snd
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, does running `sudo modprobe pcspkr` make any difference?

Comment: No joy, unfortunately :-(
Would you expect that command to give any output when run? It said nothing when I executed it. I even tried -v and --verbose. The manual says modprobe usually only prints messages if something goes wrong.

Comment: That should load the relevant module, try using the soundcard after running that command.

Comment: By try using the soundcard if you meant play something with sound, yes, that's precisely what I tried right after running the command.

Comment: Hmm, OK on my system that's the module that lets the machine beep at me, I was hoping that loading that would fix your issues. The `modprobe` command should give no output but you can check if the module was correctly loaded with `lsmod | grep pcspkr`. Your card is associated with the `snd_intel8x0` dirver, could you post the output of `lsmod | grep snd`?

Comment: Thanks. Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8793480

Comment: What is the output of `pactl list` and `amixer`

Comment: This sounds like your problem: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=196&t=117800

Comment: @terdon - see my link above, I have no way to confirm this on Mint, maybe you can.

Answer (score 1):

I installed gnome-alsamixer and when I opened it and it had some set to be mute. Unmute the *Master M* and sound works!

One hitch though, when I restart it goes back to mute format, I'll update this answer if I find a fix for that. But I guess it's not as bad as no sound at all.

Answer (score 0):

command-line solution:

alsamixer

Master, Master M, Headphone and PCM have to be unmuted ('M' toggles on/off)